# Is there a solution to improve the quality of life for my basset hound?

Tags: dogs, health, psychology, vocalizations

Our basset hound is 16 years old.  Here are his symptoms: vision almost gone, hearing almost gone, back legs very weak and sometimes needs help to stand up, no control over urinary and bowl movements.  He stays outside all day and sleeps in the garage at night.  During the day he is ok, but last 3 nights have been terrible.  He barks all night long constantly and when we get him out of his sitting bed, this process makes him pee, and he walks around and then is fine.  Last night he licked up all his pee from the floor. He does have good appetites and eats well.  But last 3 nights he barks very loudly & constantly until he is helped multiple times at night.  Also his stomach makes a noise. Is there anything to help the dog feel comfortable at night, or is it his time to go?

Comment: Can't easily answer that - that'd be a question for a vet.

Comment: We have several questions about [euthanasia here](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euthanasia) your story sounds similar to [Considering euthanasia for my aging dog](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/8006) so you might get some thoughts there.